# call a function in child component not set parent state in react js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm calling a function in my child component that is passed to child with props , and in this function I want to change parent's state but it not work; all of values passed true but setItems not work and I don't know what can I do .
it is my child component :

```js
export default function CartableList(props) {

function handleCallDetails(id, org) {
        (props.handleSetItems)(items); // items that passed are true
    }
.
.
.

return (
.
.
.
<Link
      to={{
            pathname: `/${window.location.pathname.split('/')[1]}/${props.orgID}/approval/cartable/details/${item.id}`,
                                        search: `?current=${props.mode}`,
                                    }}
                                    onClick={() => handleCallDetails(item.id)}
                                    className="drt_ItemLinkEl" />
.
.
.
);
.
.
.
}
```

There is my parent component :

```js
export default function Cartable(props) {

    const [items, setItems] = useState(null);

function handleSetItems(val) {
        // val is true but setItems not work
        setItems(...val);
    }

console.log('items : ' , items); // always show null and can not pass items to another component beacause it's null
```

Comment: Why do you pass `true`? You would have to pass an actual array of items.

Comment: Can you please provide a [Minimal, ***Complete***, and ***Repropducible***](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) component code example? Other than you are obviously logging `items` *somewhere* we've not enough context to reproduce the issue you have. Likely it is because react state updates are asynchronous and you are simply logging the current state.

Answer (score 0):

```
function handleCallDetails(id, org) {
        (props.handleSetItems)(items);
    }
```

in this funtion you are not using any of the argument you get(id ,org).
and in here:

```
onClick={() => handleCallDetails(item.id)}
```

your passing id but in component you expect to get array

and why there is a onClick in a Link, when page changes state get back to initial state.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `props.items` in place of `items` while calling the `props. handleSetItems`